# How should we manage magento versions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently there are some tags ce-1.7, ce-1.7.22, ee-1.12 and so on.

I think it would make sense to limit this to the second-point releases as the last-point releases (such as 1.7.0.2) usually do not change so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think tagging is good, and why not have a tag for ce-1.7.0.2 and one for ce-1.7 and if you use 1.7.0.2 just use both :)

Comment: because if you specify a `ce-1.3` tag people will ask you for a clarification. because different versions of 1.3.x.x (and 1.4.x.x also) have significant changes.

Comment: Yes, but the option to see all 1.3 questions AND to see all 1.3.0.4 (whatever) is good. and it is not much work while adding a question.

Comment: Your point is clear. Now the question is under what circumstances one may want to pull all 1.3 questions?

Comment: good question :) no idea

Comment: in this case my way of tagging works better. because at least the purpose is clear :-)

Answer (score 6):

I personally prefer to have a full version in a tag. It removes any additional questions for a version clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with only the edition (community or enterprise) and then only the first 2 values of the release.

i.e. ce-1.7

@Tim has a point in 1.3.x.x and 1.4.x.x but those are only exceptions to the general rule.

And I don't dare say those are obsolete versions but they are becoming rarer

Comment: Any arguments for?

Comment: I think a swamp of tags would not be beneficial to find stuff and could potentially lead to a lot of repetition of questions

Comment: As I already told to Fabian .. Your point is clear. Now the question is under what circumstances one may want to pull let's say all 1.3 questions?

Comment: Back at you: Under what circumstances one might want to pull all 1.7.0.1 questions and leave out all 1.7.0.2 and 1.7.0.0 ones?

Comment: never. the point of full tag is to show the version of Magento so no additional questions will be asked.

Comment: Well I think the version question would not be asked on every individual post, but the same question would be asked for each individual version. "Ho do I do X? [tag:1.7.0.2]", "Ho do I do X? [tag:1.7.0.1]", "Ho do I do X? [tag:1.7.0.0]", etc

Comment: People obsess with all the dots because the bruhaha around `1.4.2` or `1.4.3` or whatever it was when the magento-verse passed too close to a dwarf star and altered course forever. `1.7` is `1.7` and that's about all that's needed since `1.5`. A better tag would be to highlight BIG and dangerous changes between versions; major or minor.